# tomcat startup takes almost 3 minutes, thread is runnable with same stack

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-transactions

Tomcat startup takes almost 3 minutes. Upon investigation, I see that one of the thread is having the following stack:
Repeatedly took thread dump on the same thread and I always got same stack. Don't understand, why is it spending so much time there? Any suggestions what to look for now?

openjdk-11 and tomcat 8.5.70.0

The class has @Transactional annotation on which setter injection is called.

```
 "localhost-startStop-1" #25 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=41832.87ms elapsed=43.36s tid=0x00007fc884005800 nid=0x7a runnable  [0x00007fc8c2123000]
    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.equal(ReferenceType.java:1236)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.findDerivativeType(ReferenceType.java:1265)
    - locked <0x000000052494f838> (a java.util.ArrayList)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.TypeFactory.createParameterizedType(TypeFactory.java:43)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType.parameterize(ResolvedType.java:2555)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedMemberImpl.parameterize(ResolvedMemberImpl.java:898)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedMemberImpl.parameterizedWith(ResolvedMemberImpl.java:795)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedMemberImpl.parameterizedWith(ResolvedMemberImpl.java:743)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.getDeclaredMethods(ReferenceType.java:865)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType$MethodGetterIncludingItds.get(ResolvedType.java:273)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType$MethodGetterIncludingItds.get(ResolvedType.java:270)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.Iterators$4$1.hasNext(Iterators.java:213)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.Iterators$6.hasNext(Iterators.java:288)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.Iterators$4.hasNext(Iterators.java:230)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType.lookupResolvedMember(ResolvedType.java:642)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.JoinPointSignatureIterator.findSignaturesFromSupertypes(JoinPointSignatureIterator.java:192)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.JoinPointSignatureIterator.hasNext(JoinPointSignatureIterator.java:68)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.SignaturePattern.matches(SignaturePattern.java:320)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.KindedPointcut.matchInternal(KindedPointcut.java:202)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.Pointcut.match(Pointcut.java:137)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.AndPointcut.matchInternal(AndPointcut.java:56)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.Pointcut.match(Pointcut.java:137)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.OrPointcut.matchInternal(OrPointcut.java:60)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.Pointcut.match(Pointcut.java:137)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.ShadowMunger.match(ShadowMunger.java:113)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.Advice.match(Advice.java:113)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelAdvice.match(BcelAdvice.java:161)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelClassWeaver.match(BcelClassWeaver.java:3328)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelClassWeaver.match(BcelClassWeaver.java:2704)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelClassWeaver.weave(BcelClassWeaver.java:483)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelClassWeaver.weave(BcelClassWeaver.java:103)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weave(BcelWeaver.java:1712)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weaveWithoutDump(BcelWeaver.java:1656)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weaveAndNotify(BcelWeaver.java:1421)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weave(BcelWeaver.java:1195)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.WeavingAdaptor.getWovenBytes(WeavingAdaptor.java:551)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.WeavingAdaptor.weaveClass(WeavingAdaptor.java:387)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj.preProcess(Aj.java:116)
    - locked <0x00000004e122b088> (a org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.context.weaving.AspectJWeavingEnabler$AspectJClassBypassingClassFileTransformer.transform(AspectJWeavingEnabler.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2427)
    - locked <0x000000051b845a00> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:876)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1379)
    - locked <0x000000051b845a00> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1223)
    at org.springframework.core.ReactiveAdapterRegistry$ReactorRegistrar.registerAdapters(ReactiveAdapterRegistry.java:210)
    at org.springframework.core.ReactiveAdapterRegistry.<init>(ReactiveAdapterRegistry.java:76)
    at org.springframework.core.ReactiveAdapterRegistry.getSharedInstance(ReactiveAdapterRegistry.java:190)
    - locked <0x00000004e2341c88> (a java.lang.Class for org.springframework.core.ReactiveAdapterRegistry)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.<init>(TransactionAspectSupport.java:185)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.<init>(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:56)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect.<init>(AnnotationTransactionAspect.aj:49)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect.ajc$postClinit(AnnotationTransactionAspect.aj:1)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect.<clinit>(AnnotationTransactionAspect.aj:46)
    at com.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxxx.xx.xxxxx.jpa.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.setxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx(xxxxxxxxxxxx.java:2244) <-----------------------
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@11.0.12/Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@11.0.12/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@11.0.12/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@11.0.12/Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl$BeanPropertyHandler.setValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:332)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.processLocalProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:278)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:266)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:79)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1735)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1447)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$166/0x0000000840542840.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    - locked <0x00000004e21f2bb0> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:760)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:720)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1425)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$166/0x0000000840542840.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    - locked <0x00000004e21f2bb0> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1425)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$166/0x0000000840542840.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    - locked <0x00000004e21f2bb0> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1447)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$166/0x0000000840542840.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    - locked <0x00000004e21f2bb0> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1447)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$166/0x0000000840542840.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    - locked <0x00000004e21f2bb0> (a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:241)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:723)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:536)
    - locked <0x00000004e25213e0> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4763)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5232)
    - locked <0x00000004e0116b60> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    - locked <0x00000004e0116b60> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1177)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1925)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(java.base@11.0.12/Executors.java:515)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(java.base@11.0.12/FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@11.0.12/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@11.0.12/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.12/Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: Difficult to say without the sourcecode. Though I assume your classpath is quite big and the function searches the whole classpath. A strategy would be to set a breakpoint inf the function to find out what exactly it is searching. With that information you might find a strategy how to optimize that search.

Comment: On the other hand you should ask yourself if you really need to do this query at the startup time of your application (blocking the startup) or if you could simply do it asynchronously after the start of your application. Maybe you do not need value when the application starts but only for the first request (which might come 4 minutes after the application started and had enough time to get that value)

Comment: Don't use transactions for setter methods, as a transaction isn't needed to set some property. You probably running into some deadlock issue here, as you are probably injecting a repository that requires an JPA thing, which also needs the database. So kind of a deadlock here.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Weird thing is, I am just containerizing the existing tomcat application. The same tomcat application starts within 15 secs in VM environment and I expected the timing to stay within the same range. The difference is, jre version (jre8 -> jre 11).  Per the stack, it seems to be iterating over ResolvedMember but not clear  what it is doing. I was looking at the AnnotationTransactionAspect code but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: Also the number of jars in the classpath is almost the same between the vm environment and the docker container environment.

Comment: I removed class level Transactional annotation and now I don't see setter injection coming in the way but still taking more than 3 mins. Took stack dump and also put some breakpoints and I see all spring aspect and aspectj code in the stack (similar to what I posted above). As execution hit the breakpoint at (.transform(AspectJWeavingEnabler.java:122)) many times, I checked the incoming classname and in the later part of the execution, I see reactor, io.reactive classes. Not sure what to infer from it but code doesn't seem to be deadlocked or waiting on something.

Comment: Figured that startStopThreads is set to 0 in server.xml (tomcat running in vm environment) and saw 4 localhost-startStopThreads in the log.. but the same settings in NOT having effect in tomcat container. It continues to use just one thread.